# Close all of ui-select drop down list programmatically?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-select

I am trying to build a directive to make angular UI $uibModal draggable. And also I want to close all of opened drop down list of ui-select in the modal body, when the modal is dragging.

Does anyone know how to close all of `ui-select` list in a `$uibModal`?

jsbin
https://jsbin.com/lopitopiwa/edit?html,js,output

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('uibModalDragging',[
    UibModalDragging
]);


function UibModalDragging() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,

        link: function (scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
            $(iElem).closest('.modal-content').draggable({
                handler: '.panel-heading',
                start: onStart
            })
        }
    };

    function onStart() {
        //*********************************************
        //close all ui-select ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is better approach but you will need to create another directive according to this:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/Accessing-$select

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myUiSelect', function() {
  return {
    require: 'uiSelect',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, $select) {
      scope.$on('closeAll', (ev,val)=>{
        $select.close();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

and then add it to your elements:

```
<ui-select my-ui-select ng-model="selected.value">
                    <ui-select-match>
                        <span ng-bind="$select.selected.name"></span>
                    </ui-select-match>
                    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in myModalCtrl.itemArray">
                        <span ng-bind="item.name"></span>
                    </ui-select-choices>
              </ui-select>
```

after that just broadcast event to close everything example here:

https://jsbin.com/cadekafata/1/edit?html,js,console,output